# Any HTTPS clients without SNI support in repositories?

Tags: https

I want to test how my server behaves for a client that have a switch for disabling or doesn't have [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) support at all. Preferably, one with a command-line interface and in official repositories.

Can I disable SNI in `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: Install Wine and then `winetricks ie6`? :P

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12942331/2072269 (conditions required for SNI-supporting `curl`)

Comment: Thanks, both comments are useful. `ie6` is an option and if you want, you can post it as an answer and I'll mark it as a solution until a better one appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openssl s_client` without specifying `-servername`:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect ###.###.###.###:443 2>/dev/null | awk '/Certificate chain/,/---/'
```

vs

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect domain.name:443 -servername domain.name 2>/dev/null | awk '/Certificate chain/,/---/'
```

Comment: Note that you need `-noservername` in new OpenSSL versions, as using SNI is the default, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50770880/4454665)